# Dynamic Jasper DynamicReportBuilder - insert page break when columns run off the page

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

```
    for (GridColumnsEnum abscol : abscols) {
        drb.addColumn(abscol);
    }
```

I have a for loop that iterates through a collection of abstract columns and adds the abstract columns to a DynamicReportBuilder object.  The number of columns added to the DynamicReportBuilder object is dynamic and can range from 5-20.

The drb object is used to generate a report that is landscape oriented.  The columns frequently run off the page if there are more than 7-8 columns.

I'd like to know the best way to insert a 'page break' if there are more than 7-8 columns so that the remaining columns are displayed on the next page instead of running off the page.

I've tried various things with the DynamicReportBuilder api - namely, DynamicReportBuilder.setColumnsPerPage(7) - which doesn't seem to have any effect - the columns are not split into separate pages after the 7th column.

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you share your code please, i have the same problem and this is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498123/how-to-add-columns-to-the-new-page-in-jasperreports-report-when-exceed-the-width . may we can solve it together.[linke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498123/how-to-add-columns-to-the-new-page-in-jasperreports-report-when-exceed-the-width)