# can we use Pagebreak in jasperreport to go to new page after certain number of column?

Tags: jasper-reports, page-break

I want to display my report in new page after certain number of column. let say i have 50 columns and 10 rows in my report. i want to display every page with 25 column. It means i should have two pages every page with 25 columns.

Does any smart guy know how and where to put break in my report to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve by placing the 'Column Break' Element in your report, to achieve this you can follow these steps:

1. You need to drag and place **break** element in from the palette in iReport/Jaspersoft Studio.
2. Then in case of iReport you need to choose the break type as '**Column**' and similarly in case of Jasper Reports
3. Then you need to set a **Print When Expression** for the break element as you want the break to occur after 25 columns.
4. I think you should try the table component, which offers the possiblity to hide unused columns using a printWhenExpression.

This is how you can achieve the solution for your problem.

Thanks

Comment: I don't use ireprot. i just create everything in my code. here ie the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498123/how-to-add-columns-to-the-new-page-in-jasperreports-report-when-exceed-the-width